# XML unexpected end of file

Tags: android

i tried to build my app, but i get this error: 
Unexpected end of file. I already tried figuring out on myself, but i couldn't find the fault. So help is welcome :)

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="438dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Any good tools/sites to see what i do wrong?

Comment: you have opened `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` but didn't close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember! 
these kind of problems occur only when u have forgotten to close the openned tags or added extra angle bracket!
& something like that! be sure before posting that u have checked all these things!

here u are missing this at the end of the file....

```
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, your `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` is not closed.
So adding this line to the end should solve your problem:
`</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>`